# Problems with BeautifulSoup and lxml parser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I noticed a strange behavior when scraping some webpages using BeautifulSoup 4.1.0 and the lxml parser. The built-in html.parser didn't work for the webpage I was trying to scrape and I decided to use a lxml parser.

The result of the print on my Eclipse console looks good for a fraction of a second and then, it automatically switches to an incomplete, useless and not-so-good-looking output with spaces between all the characters:

```
                           ! - -   S w i t c h   - - &gt;                

                     / d i v &gt;
```

The doc-type of the page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I was wondering if any of you guys encountered a similar problem and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It happens, paste  some sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To help people with this problem I wrote ["Extra spaces in documents parsed by Beautiful Soup: the definitive guide"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beautifulsoup/B2KnMSrZUFs/za1FDU0yde8J). Basically, the problem is caused by a bug in lxml's HTML parser, triggered by HTML documents that include a  tag that defines the charset as other than UTF-8.

Please let me know if the suggestions in that document don't work for you.

Comment: Thanks Leonard. I'm using BS4.1, lxml-3.2.1 so Steps 1 and 2 are OK. Concerning Step 4, when I replace ISO-8859-1 characters to utf-8, I get an output that looks like:
`<html><body><addinfourl at="" fp="&lt;socket._fileobject" object="" whose="">&gt;</addinfourl></body></html>`
I tried two different sites and the output is the same for both.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
newsoup = str(soup).replace(" ", "")
```

and managed to pull out the info I needed with lxml. Using the html5lib parser also solve the problem and gave me a clean print.